# Copy Input + Link with href change +1

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, clone

i'm using filemanager on my website, and i want to make file selection. Right now i'm using jQuery relCopy.

I've got in my HTML file

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       var id=12;
       var selectFile = "<a style='float:left;' id='lightbox' class='fancybox fancybox.iframe remove' type='button' href='../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=" + iD + "'>Wybierz plik</a>";
       $('a.copy').relCopy({ append: selectFile});
       id++;
});
</script>
<p class="clone">
    <input name="pole[]" class="input" id="1" type="text" value="">
</p>

<a style="float:left;" id="lightbox" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" type="button" href="../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=1">Wybierz plik</a>

<p style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <a href="#" class="copy" rel=".clone">add another file</a>
</p>
```

It's working fine because it's cloning input and create link to file manager with field_id = input id , but only 1 time.

first input got id = 1, after click on add another file i got second input with id = 2 and link to filemanager with field_id=12, after next click on add next file id doesn't increase to 13.

in code i have id++; but it doesn't remember that id.

How i can fix this, beacuse without that filemanager is useless beacuse he will releate to the wrong input.

Comment: I was rewriting your a tag (as there are WAY easier ways in jQuery to rewrite that) and noticed 2 problems. A) are you selecting that html? if so just `var selFile = $('#lightbox')` and B) `fancybox.iframe` is not good class name practice as `$('.fancybox.iframe')` would look for an element that contains both `fancybox` and `iframe` as class names, not `fancybox.iframe`. You'd then have to excape the dot i think, something like `$('.fancybox\.iframe')` which could just get confusing

Comment: why are you using a plugin .. use jquery.clone instead

Comment: Ok i will try to do it with jquery clone. I will give you feedback.